# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un select a la tabla mysql.user en MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Si hago el siguiente select  `select User, Password from mysql.user;` me arroja los datos que quiero: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El usuario juan yo lo creé y le puse como contraseña el valor 456. Ahora cuando lo quiero buscar en la tabla no me aparece:

`select User, Password from mysql.user where User='juan' and Password='456';` o este

`select User, Password from mysql.user where User='juan' and Password= 456;`

Me arroja 0 filas. ¿Algo estoy haciendo mal?:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fila del Usuario de nombre Juan, tienes en la Columna Password lo que parece ser una encriptación de tu contraseña.

Comment: En la consulta insertas el parámetro de la contraseña sin el codificador que hayas usado previamente para encriptar tu contraseña, por lo que al llamarlo no encuentra ninguna coincidencia

Comment: Tienes que desencriptar tu contraseña para que te arroje algún resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si aplique lo mismo para `mysql` pero en MariaDB se puede usar esto:

```
SELECT 
    host, user, password 
FROM mysql.user
WHERE 
    user = '<usuario>' 
    AND password = PASSWORD('<password>');
```

Donde la magia la hace la función `PASSWORD()`.

Y bueno, pues, volviendo al asunto en tu pregunta, claro que estás haciendo algo mal, ya que `456` no es igual a `*531E182E2F...`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Cuauhtli. He resuelto el problema. La función mágica es PASSWORD().

Answer (score 1):

Puedes consular sobre el tema**[Encryption and Compression Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html)**

**Ejemplo**

```
INSERT INTO user (User, Password) VALUES ("Juan",sha1("456"));
```

**Consulta**

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE User = "Juan" AND Password = sha1("456");
```

Debiera arrojarte la consulta

Comment: Pero yo cree el usuario de esta manera: create user 'juan'@'localhost' identified by '456';
grant all privileges on checada5.* to juan@localhost;

Comment: En la descripción de la pregunta deberías poner todo lo relacionado con el tema, para que los miembros de stackoverflow puedan ayudarte a resolver tu duda.